# Error: 'ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars', while converting dict to json

Tags: json, dictionary, pytorch, tensor

The dictionary consist of key as file name which is in string format and value as embedding in tensor format.
It looks like

```py
dict = {'file_name_1': tensor([emb_1]) , 'file_name_2': tensor([emb_2]) , 'file_name_3': tensor([emb_3])}
```

While saving the dict to json format, I am getting below error-

---

```
TypeError: Object of type Tensor is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried below code:-

```py
with open("savedata.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(dict, write_file, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert your tensors into an array or a list, then you can save it into a json file because it cannot serialize the tensors directly.